# Node.js child_process exec, stdin not being passed through to ssh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, stdin, child-process

I have the following Node.js code to ssh into a server and it works great forwarding stdout, but whenever I type anything it is not forwarding to the server. How do I forward my local stdin to the ssh connections stdin?

```
var command = 'ssh -tt -i ' + keyPath + ' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@' + hostIp;

var ssh = child_proc.exec(command, {
    env: process.env
});

ssh.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

ssh.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.error(data.toString());
});

ssh.on('exit', function (code) {
    process.exit(code);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways to go about this if you want to pipe the `process.stdin` to the child process:

- Child processes have a [`stdin`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin) property that represents the stdin of the child process. So all you should need to do is add `process.stdin.pipe(ssh.stdin)`
- You can specify a custom [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) when spawning the process to tell it what to use for the child process's stdin:

  ```
  child_proc.exec(command, { env: process.env, stdio: [process.stdin, 'pipe', 'pipe'] })
  ```

Also, on a semi-related note, if you want to avoid spawning child processes and have more programmatic control over and/or have more lightweight ssh/sftp connections, there is the [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module.

Comment: Using `process.stdin.pipe(ssh.stdin)` seems to mostly worked, except it duplicates the command you type. For example: https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/cb7ffc11b764dc642325

Comment: If you don't want the local input to show, you can enable raw mode with `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)`.

Comment: Almost, except each character I type is now on a newline. See: https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/cb7ffc11b764dc642325

Comment: Change your `ssh.stdout` and `ssh.stderr` handlers to instead pipe, `ssh.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)` and `ssh.stderr.pipe(proces.stderr)` respectively. The reasoning is that `console.*` methods append a newline to the output.

Comment: Answer should be updated to include info from above comment